# I am trying to read the live events from an IoTHub device - in the same manner that Azure IotHub Explorer does when you select a device

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

As I understand it the correct way to read events is to use the `EventProcessorClient` but I am having some trouble understanding the concepts behind this.

The code below fetches a few events and then stops and never seems to fetch any new events.

What I really want is to only fetch new events.

IotHub is just another class that stores the fetched events and makes them available to the applications UI.

```
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer;
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Processor;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Framing;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StationManager
{
    internal class EventHub
    {

        static string storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxxxx;AccountKey=kkkkkkkk;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        static string blobContainerName = "blobcontainer";

        static string eventHubsConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxxxyyyyy.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=kkkkkkkkk;EntityPath=iothub-hhhhhhhhhh";
        static string ddd = "HostName=Hub.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=ffffff";
        static string eventHubName = "iothub-hhhhhhhhhh";
        static string consumerGroup = "$Default";

        BlobContainerClient storageClient;

        EventProcessorClient processor;

        ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> partitionEventCount = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();

        CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource;
        IoTHub iotHub;

        public async void Stop()
        {
            cancellationSource.Cancel();
        }
        public async void Start(IoTHub iothub)
        {
            iotHub = iothub;

             storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(
                storageConnectionString,
                 blobContainerName);

             processor = new EventProcessorClient(
                storageClient,
                consumerGroup,
                eventHubsConnectionString,
                eventHubName);

            try
            {
                cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                //cancellationSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

                processor.ProcessEventAsync += processEventHandler;
                processor.ProcessErrorAsync += processErrorHandler;

                try
                {
                    iotHub?.DidReceiveTelemetry("Started receiving.");
                    await processor.StartProcessingAsync(cancellationSource.Token);
                    await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationSource.Token);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException te)
                {
                    // This is expected if the cancellation token is
                    // signaled.
                    iotHub?.DidReceiveTelemetry($"Cancelled.");
                }
                finally
                {
                    // This may take up to the length of time defined
                    // as part of the configured TryTimeout of the processor;
                    // by default, this is 60 seconds.

                    await processor.StopProcessingAsync();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // The processor will automatically attempt to recover from any
                // failures, either transient or fatal, and continue processing.
                // Errors in the processor's operation will be surfaced through
                // its error handler.
                //
                // If this block is invoked, then something external to the
                // processor was the source of the exception.
            }
            finally
            {
                // It is encouraged that you unregister your handlers when you have
                // finished using the Event Processor to ensure proper cleanup.  This
                // is especially important when using lambda expressions or handlers
                // in any form that may contain closure scopes or hold other references.

                processor.ProcessEventAsync -= processEventHandler;
                processor.ProcessErrorAsync -= processErrorHandler;

                iotHub?.DidReceiveTelemetry("Stopped receiving.");
            }

        }
        async Task processEventHandler(ProcessEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                // If the cancellation token is signaled, then the
                // processor has been asked to stop.  It will invoke
                // this handler with any events that were in flight;
                // these will not be lost if not processed.
                //
                // It is up to the handler to decide whether to take
                // action to process the event or to cancel immediately.

                if (args.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }

                string partition = args.Partition.PartitionId;
                string deviceId = (string)args.Data.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"];
                DateTime timestamp = (DateTime)args.Data.SystemProperties["iothub-enqueuedtime"];
                byte[] eventBody = args.Data.EventBody.ToArray();
                var eventProperties = args.Data.Properties;
                //Debug.WriteLine($"Event from partition {partition} with length {eventBody.Length}.");

                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventBody);
                string evt = $"{partition}: {deviceId}, {timestamp}\n{data}";
                iotHub?.DidReceiveTelemetry(evt);

                int eventsSinceLastCheckpoint = partitionEventCount.AddOrUpdate(
                    key: partition,
                    addValue: 1,
                    updateValueFactory: (_, currentCount) => currentCount + 1);

                if (eventsSinceLastCheckpoint >= 50)
                {
                    await args.UpdateCheckpointAsync();
                    partitionEventCount[partition] = 0;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // It is very important that you always guard against
                // exceptions in your handler code; the processor does
                // not have enough understanding of your code to
                // determine the correct action to take.  Any
                // exceptions from your handlers go uncaught by
                // the processor and will NOT be redirected to
                // the error handler.
            }
        }

        Task processErrorHandler(ProcessErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in the EventProcessorClient");
                Debug.WriteLine($"\tOperation: {args.Operation}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"\tException: {args.Exception}");
                Debug.WriteLine("");
            }
            catch
            {
                // It is very important that you always guard against
                // exceptions in your handler code; the processor does
                // not have enough understanding of your code to
                // determine the correct action to take.  Any
                // exceptions from your handlers go uncaught by
                // the processor and will NOT be handled in any
                // way.
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `EventProcessorClient` is very useful when you need checkpoints. A checkpoint stores the time where you last read events. In your scenario, you don't seem to care about checkpoints, but instead only care about the last events. If so, you can use the `EventHubConsumerClient` instead. The `ReadEventsAsync` has an overload with a boolean parameter. When set to false, you will only receive new messages.

```cs
await using var consumerClient = new EventHubConsumerClient(EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName, "REDACTED");

// consumerClient.ReadEventsAsync(false) means it starts reading at the end
await foreach (PartitionEvent partitionEvent in consumerClient.ReadEventsAsync(false))
{
    string readData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(partitionEvent.Data.Body.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine($"Read event of length {readData.Length} from partition {partitionEvent.Partition.PartitionId}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Message: {readData}");
}
```

Mind you, there is a way to set a start time for the `EventProcessorClient` as well, it's described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65115522/8800237). *However*, this only works if there is no existing checkpoint. Otherwise that will take precedence.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go.  I forgot to ask how to filter based on just a single device .

Comment: IoT Hub doesn't really offer much in that scenario. You can either filter it out client side (ignoring messages other than the one you need), or create a Message Route specifically for that device and routing messages from that device to the built-in endpoint (or any other custom endpoint).